# How to define an internet brower for gmailr authentication?

Tags: r, nix, gmailr, gargle, home-manager

I use `gmailr` to retrieve emails from a gmail account. Due to my system configurations (nix home-manager on Debian), when `gmailr` needs an interactive connection to gmail, nothing happens, it just waits forever.

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

It was working fine, until I remove the old brower form `/usr/bin/`, and install it through nix to `~/.nix-profile/bin/`.
Is there a way to tell `gmailr` or `gargle` maybe, which browser to use for the authentication procedure?

I wasn't able to find something in docs or google.

Edit:
I now found, that the problem relies on the way `gmailr` starts the browser from the system environment, I get this error:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
/usr/bin/env: ‘.nix-profile/bin/brave’: No such file or directory
```

So I need to find a way to override the environment path....

Answer (score 0):

I realize that there is an option in R for selecting the default browser!

So I just put `options(browser = "x-www-browser")` in my `gmailr` script or in my `.Rprofile`. Where "x-www-browser" is a system alias for my selected browser, but it can be any system path.